# Filling holes with grid fill

Tags: python

This required an even number of vertices to fill a hole. I'd like to do this with python script, but if the non manifold edge outline has a uneven number of vertices, it will not fill. 
I may have five holes in a mesh that need filling in one go.

Any ideas how to make each hole have an even number with python?

Comment: Subdivide an edge, that will add a vertex (so that it is even). Apply grid fill. Dissolve the added vertex (should make a tri, but that's needed).

Comment: Yes that works..but I need the python script to detect that the number of vertices in an edge loop is uneven and make it even, so I can apply the grid fill.

Comment: I suppose the holes are selected or so? If yes with bmesh you should run along their edges (these edges are corresponding to only one face) so you can isolate each region (hole). From that count each loop and see which is even or not.